# Finite group has a generating set

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Show that there exists a generating set $S$ of $G$ with $|S| \le \log_2 |G|$.

I started looking what can I get if I look at generating sets of elements of $G$,i.e., $<x_1>,<x_1,x_2>,<x_1,x_2,x_3>...$ and yet I'm not sure how can I limit it as required.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea: simply pick elements successively so that the next one is not in the generated subgroup of the elements you already picked. In each step, the size of the generated subgroup at least doubles. 
This solves the problem with $n$ elements where $n$ is the upper floor of $\log_2 |G|$. To improve this, we break the problem to two cases.

Case 1: If every element has order 2 or 3 in $G$. Then by Cauchy's theorem, $|G|= 2^k3^m$. By Burnside's theorem, $G$ is solvable:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_theorem

So there is a sequence of groups, each an extension of the previous one by $\mathbb{Z}_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Thus we can pick the new elements successively so that in the i-th step we generate the i-th subgroup in the chain. This requires $k+m$ elements, which is clearly strictly less than $\log_2 |G|$.

Case 2: There is an element $g$ whose order is at least 4. Then start by this. So now instead of having the lower estimation for the size of the i-th subgroup $2^i$ (see the basic idea), we have $2^{i+1}$, as the first generated subgroup has size at least $4=2^2$. This is just enough, the number of elements is at most the upper floor of $\log_2 |G|$ minus 1 now.

Comment: Which is what I tried, but I can't say what's the size of the first generating set to begin with.

Comment: If G is trivial, you can generate with zero elements, which is good. If it is non-trivial, then pick any element different from the identity as a first one. 
If fact, the first step is no different from the others. The 1-element subgroup is generated by default, so the same rule applies: pick one that is not in the subgroup generated by the elements you already picked (no elements picked, so the generated subgroup is the trivial one).

Comment: I meant, the first generating set with one element, which is not the identity. How can I know it's size?

Comment: I understood you, and I answered your question. It is irrelevant. The only important thing is that is is at least two (if you pick a nontrivial element first).

Comment: Why is it irrelevant? Could you provide a full explanation?

Comment: I already have.

Comment: No, you didn't explain why it isn't relevant.

Comment: Is your point that I only managed to solve the problem with $n$ elements where $n$ is the upper floor of $\log_2 |G|$, instead of lower floor? I can fix that.